# std::sort giving very strange results

Tags: c++, stl

I have managed to find a reproducible example of the strange behaviour I am seeing with `std::sort`

I am trying to sort a list of pairs, where it should be sorted on the second element. The list of the second elements is `[1 1 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 1 1 5 2 1 7 1]`.

Below is my code:

```
std::vector<pair<int, double> > pairs;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    pairs.push_back(pair<int, double>(1, 1));
}
pairs.push_back(pair<int, double>(1, 3));
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    pairs.push_back(pair<int, double>(1, 1));
}
pairs.push_back(pair<int, double>(1, 3));
pairs.push_back(pair<int, double>(1, 2));
pairs.push_back(pair<int, double>(1, 1));
pairs.push_back(pair<int, double>(1, 1));
pairs.push_back(pair<int, double>(1, 5));
pairs.push_back(pair<int, double>(1, 2));
pairs.push_back(pair<int, double>(1, 1));
pairs.push_back(pair<int, double>(1, 7));
pairs.push_back(pair<int, double>(1, 1));
```

and the sorting function is:

```
template<typename T>
struct descending_sort {
    bool operator()(pair<T, double> const & a, pair<T, double> const & b) const {
        cout << "sorting (" << a.second << " , " << b.second << ")" << std::endl;
        return a.second >= b.second;
    }
};

descending_sort < int > d = descending_sort<int>();
std::sort(pairs.begin(), pairs.end(), d);
```

This produces the correct result, but when I examine a bit closely the output of the sort function at each step (what I print to console) I get some very interesting output.

The whole output can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/0WXg5s6f) but there are some strange lines (i.e. line 46 in linked page) which read:

```
sorting (0 , 1)
```

But 0 does not appear in the input list. Why is this here?

Comment: Should be `return a.second > b.second;`.

Comment: Here's a vastly more legible version of your code (with fixed predicate). http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f90bd7b88593bbf This is what your post could have looked like :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your code leads to undefined behavior, because `std::sort()` requires a strict weak ordering, which `<` or `>` provides, but `>=` does not provide because **it violates the requirement to be antisymmetric**.

Regarding `strict weak ordering`, it also include below properties

(1) **antisymmetric**

```
That for operator <: If x < y is true, then y < x is false.
That for a predicate op(): If op(x,y) is true, then op(y,x) is false.
```

(2) **transitive**

that for operator <: If x < y is true and y < z is true, then x < z is true.
   That for a predicate op(): If op(x,y) is true and op(y,z) is true, then op(x,z)
is true.

(3) **irreflexive**

```
That for operator <: x < x is always false.
That for a predicate op(): op(x,x) is always false.
```

(4) **transitivity of equivalence**, which means roughly: If a is equivalent to b and b is equivalent to c, then a is equivalent to c.

§ 25.4.4

> For all algorithms that take Compare, there is a version that uses operator< instead. That is, 1comp(*i,*j) != false1 defaults to *i < *j != false. **For algorithms other than those described in 25.4.3 to work correctly, comp has to induce a strict weak ordering on the values.**

To read more about [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html)

Comment: Can you explain what this means for the OP (and fix the paste errors)?

Comment: I wonder why `std::sort` constructs a `std::pair` on its own when the relationship is not antisymmetric.

Comment: @Lumen it's _undefined behaviour_. It doesn't "decide" to do something: it promises _not to handle_ exceptional circumstance prohibited by the specification (i.e. ill-defined comparator predicate). Whatever happens, happens.

Comment: @sehe I’m rather interested in an implementation-specific reason for the behavior, out of curiosity. The fact that the observed behavior _isn’t formally defined_ by the standard doesn’t mean there _is no reason_ for it somewhere in the used implementation of `std::sort`.

Answer (score 3):

In C++, the "compare" predicate must be a [**strict weak ordering**](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html). For example, the case `descending_sort( X, X )` (both pairs identical) should always return `false`.

Also, on this [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), it is said:

> **comp** - comparison function which returns ​true if the first argument is ***less*** than the second.

For you it means that in `descending_sort`:

```
return a.second >= b.second;
```

should be

```
return a.second > b.second;
```