# C++ STL Binary Search (lower_bound, upper_bound)

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search

I have implemented a binary search like this:

```
typedef std::vector<Cell>::iterator CellVectorIterator;

typedef struct _Point {
    char x,y;
} CoordinatePoint;

typedef struct _Cell {
    ...
    CoordinatePoint coordinates;
} Cell;

struct CellEqualityByCoordinates
{
    bool
    operator()(const Cell& cell1, const Cell& cell2) const
    { return cell1.coordinates.x == cell2.coordinates.x && cell1.coordinates.y == cell2.coordinates.y; }
};

CellVectorIterator FindCellByCoordinates (CellVectorIterator first, CellVectorIterator last, const Cell &val)
{
    return std::upper_bound(first, last, val, CellEqualityByCoordinates());
}
```

But it doesn't always find a value.

What's wrong with that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958015/stdsort-giving-very-strange-results/18958178#18958178

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparison function will not work for a binary search. It is not supposed to determine equality, it is supposed to determine an order relation. Specifically, it should return true if the first argument would definitively come before the second in a sorted range. If the arguments should be considered equal, or the second would come before the first, it should return false. Your range also needs to be sorted by this same criteria in order for the binary search to work.

An example function that might work:

```
bool operator()(const Cell& cell1, const Cell& cell2) const 
{
    if (cell1.coordinates.x < cell2.coordinates.x) return true;
    if (cell2.coordinates.x < cell1.coordinates.x) return false;
    return cell1.coordinates.y < cell2.coordinates.y;
}
```

A similar example that doubles as a lesson in short-circuit boolean evaluation would be something like:

```
bool operator()(const Cell& cell1, const Cell& cell2) const 
{
    return (cell1.coordinates.x < cell2.coordinates.x) ||
        (!(cell2.coordinates.x < cell1.coordinates.x) &&
          cell1.coordinates.y < cell2.coordinates.y);
}
```

Both exhibit a property called [**strict weak ordering**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings). It is frequently required for various sorting and/or searches in standard library collections and search algorithms.

Yet another example utilizes a `std::pair`, which already has a proper `std::less` overload available that does the above, and thus makes this considerably less complicated:

```
bool operator()(const Cell& cell1, const Cell& cell2) const
{
    return std::make_pair(cell1.coordinates.x, cell1.coordinates.y) <
           std::make_pair(cell2.coordinates.x, cell2.coordinates.y);
}
```

A similar algorithm is available for tuples via [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie).

Of course, all of this assumes you have an actual ordered sequence in the first place, ordered by the same comparison logic. (which we can only assume is true, as no evidence of such was posted).

Comment: @Barry Ben was spot-on (as usual), just brief. Maybe he had dinner waiting =P (it's happened to me).